Как передать значение в Header или Footer при использовании шаблонов
У меня возникла проблема. Я Создаю сайт с возможность войти в личный кабинет. И как принято окошко с именем пользователя находится в Header. По моей задумке рядом с аватаркой пользователя должно быть помещено имя. Я попробовал 2 способа, оба оказались не очень хорошими.
1)
Index.html:
 {{define "index"}}
        
    {{header}}
        <div id="main">
            <h1> ГЛАВНАЯ </h1>
            <h2> {{.Name}} </h2>
        </div>
    
    {{footer}}
    {{end}}

Отрывок из Header.html:

Довольно очевидно , что здесь происходит. Но в такой конфигурации я не могу передать значение в Header. До него просто не доходит информация.

Второй вариант.


Я по отдельности подгружаю каждый шаблон. Но это очевидно костыль, причем при увеличении проекта этот костыль станет проблемой.


Достаточно прописать точку. Тогда все данные перейдут из одного temple в другой.
https://habr.com/ru/articles/792802/
Здесь это подробно расписано
